# How to extract certain words from a txt into a Python variable?

Tags: python-3.x, cmd

I have a .txt file where I stored the output of a cmd command. I want to extract certain parts of the file to use them in a Python script.
The content of the text file is:

```
Profiles from interface  Wi-Fi:


Profiles from group directive (just reading)
---------------------------------------------
    <None>

Users Profiles
-------------------
    Profile from all users     : Home_Network
    Profile from all users     : Work_Network
    Profile from all users     : Stars_Wifi
```

Is there any way using `read()` and `write()` functions in Python3 where I can extract only the names of the networks in the file (Home_Network, Work_Network and Stars_Wifi) to a variable in my Python script?

Comment: Personally, I would `readline()` a line of text at a time into a string, and then use [find()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/find) (for variable-length text), or [slices](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3) (for fixed-length text) to extract the parts you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You could try reading the entire file into a variable, then using `re.findall`:

```
text = ""
with open('path/to/file.txt', 'r') as inp_file:
    text = inp_file.read()

matches = re.findall(r'Profile from all users\s*:\s*(\S+)', text)
print(matches)

['Home_Network', 'Work_Network', 'Stars_Wifi']
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the very first line `text= ""`?